# PHP no me detecta el CURL

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, curl, servidor

Buenas gente, tengo un servidor web en un Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 LTS 64-bit.
En el cual estoy instalando el GLPI, el cual me da problemas porque no detecta la extension CURL, la cual la tengo instalada, he incluso varias versiones.

Aquí esta el error:
[image]

Y como os e dicho tengo el CURL instalado, aquí la prueba:

Ya no se que hacer, al phpinfo() no me reconoce el CURL y la version de mi PHP es la 7.1.6 
Que puedo hacer?

Gracias.

La captura de la comanda 'php -i | grep curl'
[image: prova]

Comment: ¿La tienes activa en el php.ini?

Comment: Como se activa? @Lithorell

Comment: En el archivo php.ini tienes que buscar la linea `;extension=php_curl.dll`y quitar el `;` inicial

Comment: en linux no creo que tenga un dll

Comment: En linux normalmente son .so en lugar de .dll

Comment: Si, es so, puse dll por la costumbre ;)

Comment: Si no me equivoco `aptitude search paquete` busca en los paquetes del repositorio, no? a lo mejor no lo tienes instalado

Comment: @Lithorell he quitado los ';' de las extensiones en el php.ini y nada :(

Comment: @blonfu Mira la imagen que añadí , ya ejecute ese comando. Y tengo en CURL varias veces. Gracias

Comment: Por esa imagen te lo digo, estás buscando en el reposiorio no en tu máquina, por eso te aparecen tantas versiones, son los paquetes que hay disponibles para instalar

Comment: ¿Cómo instalaste cURL ... `sudo apt-get install php-curl`? [Ver esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35035211/5587982).

Comment: @A.Cedano Si exacto, tambien probe con 'php7.1-curl'  y algunas más al ver que no funciona.

Comment: ¿Qué información arroja este comando: `php -i | grep curl`. Podría ser útil para determinar el problema, puedes ponerla en la pregunta editada, ignorando información que sea personal e irrelevante.

Comment: @SoulGame se me olvido decirte que despues de quitar los puntos hay que reiniciar el servidor.

Comment: @Lithorell eso lo tenia en cuenta, no te preocupes reinicie el servidor entero :)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero intenta:
*(como root, o en su defecto utilizando sudo)*

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php-curl
```

Esto en teoría te instala las dependencias que tiene a parte de la extensión en si (apt-get update lo ejecutamos para tener los repositorios actualizados). Aún así en caso de que no funcione (o te ponga que no ha encontrado el paquete), prueba con:

```
apt-get install php7.0-curl
```

Si te funciona este último, ten en cuenta que tienes más de una versión de php instala en tu sistema.

Comment: Perfecto, me a funcionado la segunda comanda 'apt-get install php7.0-curl' muchas gracias :)